# Android ScrollView with transparency on top and bottom

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, transparency

I'm using a vertical ScrollView in Android.

I need to add transparency on the top and the bottom of the ScrollView such that its contents appear disappear gradually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to add the attributes

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="25dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the attribute `android:fadingEdgeLength="15.5sp"` The length specified will be applied to both top and bottom of the `ScrollView`

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. The functionality that I mentioned in my question hasn't been applied.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe overlay an imageview of a gradient going from background color to transparent...?